# Divide number in row by different values depending on column value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this sample dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':['row1','row2','row3','row4','row5'], 'col2':[3,3,3,2,3]})

   col1 col2
0   row1    3
1   row2    3
2   row3    3
3   row4    4
4   row5    3
```

I am trying to divide each value in a given row depending on the row I am on.  Meaning, in this example, I want the row to reflect its current value divided by 3 for the rows that have 'row1, 'row2, 'row3' and 'row5' strings in the first, but the row that has a 'row4' in the first column, that row's values should be divided by 4, resulting in this as a percentage.  i.e. 3/3 = 100%, 4/4 = 100% and so forth:

```
col1    col2
0   row1    100
1   row2    100
2   row3    100
3   row4    100
4   row5    100
```

I have tried iloc and loc (based upon some questions/answers on SO) but they all replace the value, instead of make the value a computation of its existing value and some other operation.  In this case, the value divided by a number.  Ultimately, I have a df with about 50 rows, and in some rows, the value in the row should be divided by x and in others it should be divided by y and still others divided by z.  I need to be able to target a row by the column string value in the first column and use that as the basis for determining what numerical value each cell in that row should be divided by.  I am likely missing something fundamental here, but after reviewing my own code now, I have a blind spot no doubt.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @not_speshal  By dividing the number 3/3 and multiplying that by 100 to get a percent.  i.e. 3 is 100% of 3.  My description was admittedly vague on that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [df["col1"].isin(["row1", "row2", "row3", "row5"]),
              df["col1"].eq("row4")]

choices = [df["col2"].div(3),
           df["col2"].div(4)]

df["col2"] = np.select(conditions, choices)

>>> df
   col1  col2
0  row1   1.0
1  row2   1.0
2  row3   1.0
3  row4   1.0
4  row5   1.0
```

Alternatively, creating a mapping dictionary for the divisors:

```
mapper = {"row1": 3, "row2": 3, "row3": 3, "row4": 4, "row5": 3}
df["col2"] = df["col2"].div(df["col1"].map(mapper))
```